# Passing Properties Between Winforms When Using Singleton

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, singleton

Ok so I am trying to pass a boolean from my Login form to my Home form, normally this would be fine for me and I would just use a property. However I thought I could use a similar method this time but I am implementing the singleton factory on the forms.

Here is the Login code relevant to this:
The AdminAccess property gets set fine and I have checked the value is correct.

```
private bool adminAccess;

public bool  AdminAccess
    {
        get { return adminAccess; }
        private set { adminAccess = value; }
    }

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some Code Does Stuff

         OpenHome();
    }

private void OpenHome()
    {
        HomeForm CreateHomeForm = HomeForm.HomeUI;
        CreateHomeForm.StartupHome = this;

        //Trying to set the property.
        CreateHomeForm.AdminPermissions= this.AdminAccess;

        CreateHomeForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Here is the relevant code from the Home form:

```
public HomeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //just to check what is in the property quickly
        textBox1.Text = AdminPermissions.ToString();
    }

private bool adminPermissions;
public bool AdminPermissions
    {
        private get { return adminPermissions; }
        set { adminPermissions = value; }
    }

public Form StartupHome
    {
        set;
        get;
    }

private static HomeForm homeUI;
public static HomeForm HomeUI
    {
        get
        {
            if (homeUI == null || homeUI.IsDisposed)
            {
                homeUI = new HomeForm();
            }
            return homeUI;
        }
    }
```

The value gets reset when the HomeUI if loop runs as a new instance of the form is created. I can't seem to think how to modify this to get a working solution. As you can tell I am fairly amateur so I'm just looking for a quick and clean solution to this :) 
Thank you very much for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign the value in the constructor, BEFORE the `AdminPermissions` property is actually set. Change your code like this

```
public class HomeForm
{
    public HomeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool adminPermissions;  
    public bool AdminPermissions
    {
        get { return adminPermissions; }
        set { 
            adminPermissions = value;
            textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this coupled with using the Shown event from aid given in the other answer has solved my problem! I had hoped it was me doing something silly and it was :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `textBox1.Text` value in one of the `Form` events. Try `Loaded` first, then `Activated`. You're resetting it to `false` every time in your constructor!

Comment: Thank you I tried both Load and Activated however both always showed as False!!! But it did lead to me looking up the forms Startup order of events and finding out that I needed to use the Shown event :D So thank you for your help.

Comment: @JackEker, ah, right. I can never remember the form lifetime chart. Because, well, I just look it up, when needed ;)